# set the image size to the windows size in java.how to make background image to windows size?

Tags: java, netbeans, desktop-application

background image auto adjust it self according to width and height of windows. here is my code

I am trying to make my background image responsive i.e. either i maximized the windows or minimized the windows the background image auto adjust it self

[image: I am trying to make my background image responsive i.e. either i maximized the windows or minimized the windows the background image auto adjust it self]

please help me i working on this problem more than two days but fails to complete this. please help me .

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Post the actual code in the forum. Also, post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Add the size of the window in drawImage method()

Answer (score 0):

## Try with this

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    
    public class JPanelBackground extends JPanel {
     
        private Image background;
     
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int width = this.getSize().width;
            int height = this.getSize().height;
     
            if (this.background != null) {
                //Add the size of the window in drawImage method()
                g.drawImage(this.background, 0, 0, width, height, null); 
            }
        }
     
        public void setBackground(String imagePath) {
            this.background = new ImageIcon(imagePath).getImage();
            repaint();
        }
     
    }
```

Comment: 1) there is no need to make the component non-opaque 2) the super.paintComponent() should be the first statement, not the last. The point of invoking that method is to clear the background of the panel before you draw the image in case there are any transparent pixels in the image.

Comment: using this image is not visible. just Jpanel without image :(